# How do I know when the prototype chain ends?

Tags: javascript, prototype

In the first case, the prototype chain is longer than in the second one.

```js
function Func() {};
Func.__proto__ == Function.prototype; //true
Func.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //true
Func.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //false
Func.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //Cannot read property '__proto__' of null
```

In the second case, it's shorter.

```js
let obj = {};
    obj.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //true
    obj.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //false
    obj.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //Cannot read property '__proto__' of null
```

Why? The line of the second example `obj .__ proto __.__ proto__ == Object.prototype` gives false. But in the first case, the similar line of code `Func .__ proto __.__ proto__ == Object.prototype` gives true.

What's the difference? Why does the first example have longer prototype chain than the second one? What does it depend on?

Comment: One has a longer prototype chain than the other. Because it has more things in it. How many things were in the prototype chain of the object that was the first prototype of the object you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are also Objects in Javascript. Thinking of it as levels, they are one level below Object in the chain/tree.

So if any function is defined, its `__proto__` will be `Function.prototype`. Function.prototype's `__proto__` will be `Object.prototype`.

Note: When we do `let obj ={}`, under the hood `obj` is created as an instance of Object. Any instance of Object will have its `__proto__` set to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: One good link, that helped me understand all this a **little** better https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know when the prototype chain ends?

You know when the prototype chain ends when you recursively ask for `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)` (or `foo.__proto__`) and the answer finally comes back `null`.

Prototype chains can be of any length. You could have an object with a prototype `Sailboat.prototype` which has prototype `Boat.prototype` which has prototype `Vehicle.prototype` which has prototype `Mappable.prototype` which has prototype `Object.prototype`. That's a very reasonable set of prototype relationships, and you could add something else to the beginning of it, too, if you wanted more specific types of sailboats, e.g., `Catamaran.prototype` which has prototype `Sailboat.prototype`.

In this case, a function object has prototype `Function.prototype`, which has a prototype `Object.prototype`. An object created by `{}` literal has a prototype of `Object.prototype`. In both cases, `Object.prototype` has no parent; it's the root of both chains, so `Object.prototype.__proto__` is `null`.

It's tautological to say, but a prototype chain is as long as it is. You can keep getting prototype parents until you can't anymore, and that's how long the prototype chain is.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference? Why does the first example have longer prototype chain than the second one? What does it depend on?

It's simply that the first example is a function, so it has `Function.prototype` as its direct prototype. This isn't the case in the second example, it doesn't have any special "subtype" so delegates directly to `Object.prototype`.